# Add a FormFile to an HttpRequest

Tags: c#, httprequest, integration-testing

I am trying to create a ControllerContext object to attach to my test controller. I want it to have a FormFile. This is what I am doing, but it throws:

```
   public static ControllerContext WithFiles(params IFormFile[] files)
   {
       var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
       foreach (var file in files)
       {
           var request = httpContext.Request;
           request.ContentType = "image/svg+xml"; // System.InvalidOperationException: 'Incorrect Content-Type: image/svg+xml'
           var form = request.Form;
           form.Files.Append(file);
       }
       var controllerContext = new ControllerContext
       {
           HttpContext = httpContext
       };
       return controllerContext;
   }
```

Here is an excerpt from the controller code I want to test:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> ControllerMethod() {
    var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files[0];
    byte[] buffer;
    if (!ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType)
        throw new ConstraintException("Request MIME type is invalid.");
    if (ContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Form.Files.Count < 1)
        throw new ConstraintException("Attributes file not found.");
    if (file.ContentType == "image/svg+xml") {
       // I want the test to get into this if. It does stuff with the file.
    }
  }
```

How can I get into the if statement above, with content in my file?

Comment: A MIME is multiple attachments to the body of a Request/Response.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140).  Each MIME (multi-part) attachment stats with two dashes on a new line. A IActionResult is a single object in the body of a Request/Response which is serialized/deserialized data. You can't have both.  The content type "image/svg+xml" is used only with MIME.  For Form Data try following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1

Comment: For form-data request with use [FromForm] tag